# How to manipulate MS Excel page breaks from MS Access 2003 VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have an MS Access VBA code that generates an Excel spreadsheet shown below, and I need to make my page break output from this:
[image: Wrong output]

into this:

[image: supposed output]

programmatically in MS Access VBA.

I have tried already a bunch of codes (see snippets below) but somehow none of them did the trick nor even the slightest change.

Code Snippet #1)

```
ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
ActiveSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks

i = 1
If ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count > 0 Then
    Do
        Set ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(i).Location = Range("A" & (i * 70) + 1)
        If i = ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count Then Exit Do
            i = i + 1
        Loop
End If
Do Until Cells((i * 70) + 3, 1).Value = ""
    ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Range("a" & (i * 73) + 1)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
```

Code Snippet #2)

```
Dim Rng As Excel.Range

Set Rng = xls.Rows("1:75")
Rng(75).PageBreak = -4135
```

Code Snippet #3)

```
xls.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=xls.Cells(73, 1)
```

Any assistance on this is highly appreciated. Thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not understanding your snippets very well, but based on the screenshot, you want to print it on one page containing everything. Something like this sets the print area to 1 page x 1 page in excel -

```
Sub breaks()
Dim rLastCol As Long
Dim rLastRow As Long
With ActiveSheet
rLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
rLastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    With .PageSetup
.PrintArea = Range("A1", Cells(rLastRow, rLastCol)).Address
.FitToPagesWide = 1
.FitToPagesTall = False
    End With

End With
End Sub
```

Of course, this uses the last used cell in column A and in Row 1, so the most bottom-right non-blank.

Comment: I initially required this code to run in MS Access but in the long run I figured it's best to run in the MS Excel file itself. So with a little tweaking in this code (under the .PageSetup, I added .Zoom = False, and changed the .FitToPagesTall = 1), I managed to get it to work. Thank you very much for the help. :)